# Why is my container is not using the available RAM of my host machine?

Tags: docker, memory, memory-management, docker-desktop

I'm running docker on a windows machine with 16GB RAM. 
My container uses 4GB of memory as per `docker stats`(see output below). However, there is no process as per my windows task manager taking that kind of memory, and the memory usage on my computer does not change when i start/stop my container.

Thus my questions are

1. From where the 4GB of RAM used by container is coming from (disk as RAM?)
2. How can i configure my container to use the available RAM

My container is extremely slow and I suspect its because of the above behavior; where it is using disk as virtual memory and thus not really using the resources(RAM) available to it.

```
$ docker stats

CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
66a9ccfd0a51        quirky_wozniak      0.04%               4.268GiB / 4.815GiB   88.63%              113kB / 20.2kB      40.8MB / 1.07MB     16
```

[task manager screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p0ev.png)

[Docker Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwhkJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker for Windows typically runs a VM to support Linux containers. The memory given to this VM is the memory available on the docker host. In the preferences, there is a menu to configure the number of CPU cores and amount of memory to dedicate to this VM:

[image: Advance VM settings]

(Image credit: [Docker for Windows documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/))

Comment: in Advanced VM Settings i have given 5GB of RAM and 4GB of Swap. Still the container is not using the host's RAM. to avoid ambiguity, i'm adding a screenshot of my Advanced VM settings as well

Comment: 5GB = 4.815 GiB roughly. It's a slight difference in units (binary vs 10's): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

Comment: Note the limit shown in `docker stats` doesn't factor in other processes running inside the VM on the docker host, so the container is unable to use all of that memory. Docker is just letting you know that without a limit defined, the container is allowed to use all of the host memory it can get.

Comment: If i have set a limit of 5GB for my docker VM, and if i have a process which takes 4GB running inside my container, bare minimum i expect 4GB of memory of my docker host being used.  My question is why we are not using that.

Comment: Docker runs in HyperV, not sure task manager has any visibility to VM's, it's showing you the processes running inside your current windows instance. My question is why haven't you tried adjusting the slider to give docker more memory already? I'll consider answering further comments after you make this change and show that it had no improvement for you.

Comment: I had set my slider at 5GB as it was sufficient for the application which needed only 4GB. Anyway, your comment on Task Manager was the answer to my question. The memory consumed by docker service(HyperV) is not displayed by task manager. I was always relying on task manager to tell me the my memory usage of processes. Now, i can see the missing memory in RMap under the "Driver Locked" section.

Comment: now, googling with better understanding of the problem gave more pages which explains things better. e.g. http://rajdude.com/blog/what-is-driver-locked-memory/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Task Manager doesn't consider Hyper-V as a process and thus is not displayed among the list of processes.
In other words, the memory being consumed by was not displayed by task manager anwywere other than in summary.

By using advanced tools like RMAP we can see that memory is being used under "Driver Locked" section.